# htdbm and mod_authn_dbm fail when migrating between apache 2.2 servers

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, database, gentoo, berkeleydb

I'm migrating an existing website from Apache 2.2.4 on Gentoo 32-bit to Apache 2.2.27 on CentOS 64-bit.  This particular site uses DBM for authentication with encrypted passwords.

On the old system if I type:

```
htdbm -l access.db
```

I get a list of the users in the file.

On the new system, the same command outputs:

```
Error opening database access.db
No such file or directory
```

I've checked permissions on access.db and I've tried running htdbm as root.  It has to be a format error.

Then, I discovered that Apache hadn't been compiled with --with-berkeley-db, so I enabled that and recompiled Apache.

However, now the result is:

```
Dumping records from database -- access.db
    Username                         Comment
Total #records : 0
```

I know that this particular file contains 68 records.

Interestingly, this file is reported as:

```
access.db: Berkeley DB (Hash, version 7, native byte-order)
```

Whereas I found another BDB file that did work on this system, and it showed:

```
restricted.db: Berkeley DB (Hash, version 8, native byte-order)
```

What more can I do to find out why the first file can't be read?  If it's the version, how can I convert the file to the newer version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution at this point is to use

```
db_dump
```

on the old server, and

```
db_load
```

on the new server.

I presume I could do this all on the new server if I got an old version of the BDB libraries and compiled them in using the

```
 ---with-dbm
```

flag.

However, at this time since I have working versions in both places, this is the fastest solution for me right now.